# Is there any way (built-in or not) to display a sub-tree as a top level tree when narrowed?

Tags: org-mode, doom, display, overlays, narrowing

When I narrow to a subheading in emacs, I would love for it to be displayed as if it was the *top level* as opposed to it staying the level it actually is.

For example consider this tree

```
* Heading 1
** Heading 2
*** Heading 3
**** Heading 4
***** Heading 5
foobar...
```

In my emacs displays it more like this:

```
✿ Heading 1
 ✽ Heading 2
  ❁ Heading 3
   ✤ Heading 4
    ❀ Heading 5
     foobar...
```

And if I narrow to heading 4 it displays like this:

```
   ✤ Heading 4
    ❀ Heading 5
     foobar...
```

However I would like it to display like as a 'top level' header like this:

```
✿ Heading 4
 ✽ Heading 5
  foobar...
```

And when I wide, for it to display normally again.

I'm very new to emacs, but I haven't found anyone else with this issue when searching, which suggests that either I'm doing something wrong or everyone is fine with it as is!

If the latter is the case, I know overlays could potentially provide an solution but I'm very new to lisp (and especially elisp) so I have no idea whether it's even possible or not.

I'm using the following version(s) of emacs on windows. I can attach my configs if needed!

```
GNU Emacs     v28.2            nil
Doom core     v3.0.0-pre       HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD e96624926 2023-01-01 21:55:13 -0500
Doom modules  v22.10.0-pre     HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD e96624926 2023-01-01 21:55:13 -0500
```

Comment: That's nothing that narrowing can control alone. Level beautification works based on plain text heading and the number of '*' before the line. To do that probably will require writing a mode for specialized display of narrowed org chunks